# Objects Mirroring Others

Tags: java, spring

Designing a new application, I have two sets of domain objects. One set mirrors the other and domain objects basically are paired up with similar attributes. When a domain object in the set A is created, updated, or deleted, a corresponding domain object in the set B will also be created, updated, or deleted. To reduce any coupling, I would like to separate those operations between a pair of domain objects. What will be a good mechanism to achieve this approach? I am thinking of using a messaging system. Will it work well for this case? I use Spring for this project.

Comment: To some people, any questions are too broad if they don't contain any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using application events is a common solution for decreasing coupling between objects.

Actually spring already has builtin mechanism for that.

You might come up with something like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So44490189Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So44490189Application.class, args);
    }

    public static class UserCreatedEvent {
        private final String email;

        public UserCreatedEvent(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
    }

    @Service
    public static class UserService {
        @EventListener
        public void handleUserCreatedEvent(UserCreatedEvent userCreatedEvent) {
            System.out.println("Creating user " + userCreatedEvent.email);
        }
    }

    @Service
    public static class MemberService {
        @EventListener
        public void handleUserCreatedEvent(UserCreatedEvent userCreatedEvent) {
            System.out.println("Creating member " + userCreatedEvent.email);
        }
    }

    @Service
    public static class OperationService {
        private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

        @Autowired
        public OperationService(ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher) {
            this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
        }

        public void createUser(String email) {
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(new UserCreatedEvent(email));
        }
    }

    @RestController
    public static class OperationController {
        private final OperationService operationService;

        @Autowired
        public OperationController(OperationService operationService) {
            this.operationService = operationService;
        }

        @PostMapping
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
        public void createUser(String email) {
            operationService.createUser(email);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:8080?email=admin@localhost.localdomain'
```

Output

```
Creating member admin@localhost.localdomain
Creating user admin@localhost.localdomain
```

In this case creation user and members are mirrored.

One possible problem is transaction support and there is a couple of ways to deal with that. `Spring` has tools for it as well.

Comment: This approach is better than using a message queue. I overlooked this Spring 4 feature.